# PHPFOG and MySql

Tags: mysql, connection, phpfog

I am playing around with PHPFog and as a result I ended up with a MySql database. I am trying to figure out how to connect to it with a success message.

PHPFog says use this:

```
mysql_connect(
  $server = getenv('MYSQL_DB_HOST'),
  $username = getenv('MYSQL_USERNAME'),
  $password = getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD'));
mysql_select_db(getenv('MYSQL_DB_NAME'));
```

So I basically plug my variables into the above? Or Do I do something different?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply plug your host, user, password, and database name into this. There's nothing magic about using `getenv` to retrieve those values.

But, please be aware that mysql_connect() and related functions in that PHP api have been cracked.  You should switch to using MySQLi  http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php  or PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php.

Comment: Thanks Ollie, The first time around I tried similar I got an error. Also thanks for the heads up on MySQLi.  ~Jim